# How to insert data into a JSON array inside a file?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.x, shutil

**Problem:**

I am Working on a file meta-project, which collects file information from a folder and stores it in a JSON file.

My Empty JSON file looks like this

**db.json**

```
{
    "samples" : []
}
```

Now my idea is to scan each file and insert each record into samples array like this

**db.json**

```
{
    "samples" : [
{
    "file_name": "ba18524fe5d5c6e99b99c7da66dbbfa094ab8f61",
    "file_new_location": "/home/admin/",
    "file_path": "/home/admin/vt_files/ba18524fe5d5c6e99b99c7da66dbbfa094ab8f61",
    "file_source": "VT",
    "md5": "149c4ac4ba0863607e033d6a5721fee7",
    "mime": "application_x-dosexec",
    "severity": "high",
    "sha256": "50bc946af55f0a5deb66f935229046c1ec74fb2233d71efa3ae064a073a771f5"
}
]
}
```

But My issue is when ever i try to insert records, Iam not able to insert into the samples, but are coming in a single line.

```
for file_original_name in files:
    file_meta = {}
    file_meta['file_name'] = file_original_name
    file_meta['file_path'] = os.path.join(root,file_original_name)
    file_meta['file_source'] = source
    file_meta['severity'] = severity
    file_meta['md5'] = md5(file_meta['file_path'])
    file_meta['sha256'] = sha256(file_meta['file_path'])
    mime = magic.Magic(mime=True)
    file_meta['mime'] = mime.from_file(file_meta['file_path']).replace('/','_')
    file_meta['file_new_location'] = '{}/{}/{}/{}'.format(default_root,severity,file_meta['mime'],file_original_name)
    try:
        extracted_new_dir = os.path.join(default_root,severity,file_meta['mime'])
        if not os.path.isdir(extracted_new_dir):
            os.makedirs(extracted_new_dir)
        if delete:
            move(file_meta['file_path'],file_meta['file_new_location'])
        else:
            copyfile(file_meta['file_path'],file_meta['file_new_location'])
        print json.dumps(file_meta,sort_keys=True,indent=4)
    except Exception as e:
        print e
    result[file_original_name] = (file_meta)
    with open('db.json','a') as f:
        json.dump(result , f)
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: @Sraw I want to insert into the array.

Comment: I think you need to load the whole json file first and then modify it like modifying a `dict/list`, finally dump it again.

Answer (score 0):

try to format the result first, before writing it into file:

```
result = json.dumps(r, indent=4)
with open('db.json','a') as f:
    f.write(result)
```